# How can I return an array back from a function from a LINQ anonymous list?

Tags: vb.net, linq, generics

Essentially i want to have a generic function which accepts a LINQ anonymous list and returns an array back. I was hoping to use generics but i just can seem to get it to work.

hopefully the example below helps

say i have a person object with id, fname, lname and dob.
i have a generic class with contains a list of objects.

i return an array of persons back

my code snippet will be something like

```
dim v = from p in persons.. select p.fname,p.lname
```

i now have an anonymous type from system.collections.generic.ineumerable(of t)

to bind this to a grid i would have to iterate and add to an array
e.g.

```
dim ar() as array

for each x in v
    ar.add(x)
next

grid.datasource = ar
```

i dont want to do the iteration continually as i might have different objects

i would like a function which does something like below:

```
function getArrayList(of T)(dim x as T) as array()

    dim ar() as array

    for each x in t
       ar.add(x)
    next

    return ar
end
```

hope that clarifies. how can i get a generic function with accepts an anonymous list of ienumearable and returns an array back.
unfortunately, the one i have does not work.

many thanks in advance as any and all pointers/help will be VASTLY appreciated.

regards

azad

Answer (score 3):

You can bind a grid directly to the array of anonymous types.  Here's an example:

```
        var qry = from a in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                  select new { SomeField1 = a, SomeField2 = a * 2, SomeField3 = a * 3 };
        object[] objs = qry.ToArray();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objs;
```

Note also the call to ToArray, which eliminates the need for a loop.  I also assign it to a type of object[] to demonstrate that you could pass that around as its type if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You'd just call [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx).  Sure, the type is anonymous... but because of type inference, you don't have to say the type's name.

From the example code:

```
    packages _
    .Select(Function(pkg) pkg.Company) _
    .ToArray()
```

Company happens to be string, but there's no reason it couldn't be anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, so I'm not sure how much my answers will help, but here goes...

- [An anonymous type has method scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) so you cannot return it from a function, at least not in a strongly-typed manner. [You can cast to `object` and then back to a re-creation of your anonymous type](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx), but you'd be better off declaring a simple class with some [automatic properties](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/08/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers.aspx).
- To convert an `IEnumerable` to an array, just call `ToArray()`
- However, you can `DataBind` to an `IEnumerable` directly, no need to convert it to an array
- If the data you are dealing with can have different fields then you might be best off creating a `DataTable` and binding that to your DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can easily pass anonymous objects as parameters, anymore than you can have them as return values.

I say easily, because:

- http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx
- http://blog.decarufel.net/2007/11/passing-anonymous-to-and-from-methods.html

*[Try the code formatting option on your question (the " button in the editor), it would make it easier to read the parts of your question which are code snippets.]*